# How can I push the files in a feature branch to a remote's master branch?

Tags: git, github

Say I have 2 remotes: A, and B. A's mater branch is in sync with the local master branch, and B's master branch has no file.

On my local repo, I have 2 branches: master, and feature.

How can I upload the files in the feature branch to a remote B's master branch.

Comment: Note that you push *commits*, not *files*. Each commit contains a complete snapshot of a source tree, so the commits take the files along for the ride—but Git will make more sense when you realize that you're working directly with the *commits* here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the remote and branch when performing a `push`.

Assuming that `feature` is the current branch:

```
$ git push <remote> <local_branch>:<remote_branch>
$ git push B feature:master
```