# How to push just one edit, on a file, without also pushing the rest of the history of changes, since the last release?

Tags: git, github, staging

I have 3 remotes:

- Dev
- Staging
- Live

The Dev mirrors the Local copy that I have and can be updated each time I fix a **bug**. I normally git push to **dev master**

THere are **hotfixes**, however, and those changes need to be pushed to the Live remote ASAP.

However, the Live remote must be updated with all the normal bugs solved **once a week**, every Monday, when the **release** is done.

If I solve a **hotfix** , editing a stylesheet on row 10, for instance, and I want that change to be reflected on the LIve environment but don't want to push the rest of the changes that that stylesheet has in it since last Monday, do I create a secondary branch for this hotfix(?), specifically, or what would the workflow be, for this procedure ?

It's a beginner question. Is this intended for working with branches?

( I read something related to this in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112834/how-can-i-push-the-files-in-a-feature-branch-to-a-remotes-master-branch) )

Answer (score 0):

After some documentation, I found a nifty tutorial [here](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Pushing a file's changes on the LIVE remote (without pushing it's history of edits that have been done after the release) is not possible if I didn't work on the said changes on a different branch than master.
I should have created a **dev** branch, on the **DEV** remote.
The **master** branch should have been the one that we only touch on a week-by-week basis (therefore, left untouched for 7 days, with the exception of hotfix merges).

While commiting features to the dev branch, some hotfixes would arise that would need immediate merging to the release(master) branch. Therefore, a separate hotfix-nameOfHotfix branch should be made, for the respective file edit, from the release (aka **master**) branch. Once the file has been modified, only those changes could be merged to the master, without pushing code that is not yet suitable for the curent release.

-- Once again, the **hotfix##** branch should only spawn from the **master** branch.

-- the DEV remote's **master** branch must mirror (at all times) the LIVE remote's **master** branch.

It took awhile for me to understand that Git knows where to place changes in a file, regardless if there are more than one coders that work on the same file; the conflict could come up if both coders would work on the same row of the respective file.

So, in the question I posted, I would have on the DEV remote, 3 branches:
 - dev (with an infinite lifetime)
 - master (with an infinite lifetime)
 - hotfix## (limited lifetime) - after each hotfix is finished it would be merged onto the LIVE remote's master branch and the DEV remote's master branch.

Option 1:
The LIVE remote has just the **master** branch present. (in which the **dev** branch from the DEV remote is merged.)

Option 2:
the **dev** branch from the DEV remote can also be merged on the DEV's **master** branch; 
then I can copy that master branch to the LIVE remote)